# PDI 8.2 Marketplace isn`t working on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: plugins, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, marketplace

I launch the spoon.sh and there is a button Marketplace on Pentaho`s Welcome screen. It seems to be easily pushed, but nothing happens after pushing!

Picture of the unworking button on Welcome screen

[image: Picture of the unworking button on Welcome screen]

Ways I tried to do to fix the problem which doesn`t work:

1) Run spoon.sh from sudo

2) Add extra values in .cfg file according https://community.hitachivantara.com/thread/12973-marketplace-have-problems

What else can I do to open Marketplace? It seems like a problem with dropdown windows, but also can be some another.

P.s. this happens while launching. Is it affects?

swt is not responding

[image: swt is not responding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll translate an answer on StackOverflow Pt-Br (my own answer as well).
For me the solution that worked. Close your PDI, go to your PDI installation folder:
...\data-integration\system\karaf\caches\spoon\

There can be folders named data-1, data-2 .. enter in each one and delete all the **content, JUST the content, not the entire folder**.

Execute your Spoon.sh

When i was answering that time i found some other alternatives, but that was for version 7.0, in any case, the solution was that some versions of JDK/JRE (JAVA) were incompatible. I use JRE1.8.0_181 and JDK1.8.0_131.

Comment: There was really problem with incorrect Java version!